# Getting view name which called action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got couple of idententical views. Lets say: (1) Obsolete Products (2) Live Products.

The UI is almost the same including the action methods these views call. Currently, I have gone with "status" based coding.

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(string productType, bool isObsolete)
    { 
        //some common code...

        //status passed from the view
        return isObsolete ? View("ObsoleteProducts") : View("LiveProducts");
    }
```

I don't want views to pass the status - isObsolete. Instead, action method should detect that which view has called me(action itself).

I dig into Request object and its properties, but it ofcourse has "...\GetProducts" as URI..

Comment: Really I don't get it, which is your question/trouble?

Comment: Zach.. its about... "How an action method knows which view(parent) called him" OR "How action method knows the path to itself at runtime"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are kind of limiting yourself on options by asking that the view not actually pass any information back to let you know where the request came from.

That said, you most likely need to look at the UrlReferrer property of the request to see where the request originated from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: Thanks.. It works... the catch: the request generator view can't be the default(start) view as there won't be any originator in that case..

Comment: Yup - and if someone links directly to GetProducts from an outside website, this will also fail in the sense that it won't be from liveProducts or obsoleteProducts.  Just be sure that you have a default contingency set if the referrer is something you were not expecting.

Comment: Covering catch makes the implementation fragile.. leaving the appraoch.. At the end its not "that" bad to give responsibility to views to pass(maintain) self status.